# How to get Azure Email Communication Service Connection String

Tags: azure, permissions, email-client

[image]

I recently started using azure services. I created an email communication service to handle the mail communications from the application. As per documentation, I should use email connection string to connect to the service, but I am unable to get the information from the azure portal. In my email service menu, Tools> keys not listed even though I created the service. It would be a great help if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get the keys and connection string from the `Settings`  > `Keys` menu in the communication service. Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: There is no 'Keys' option anywhere in the menu. I edited the post to add the menu option. I kind of noticed that there is no 'Keys' option available any of the portal resources.

Comment: You should look into Communication Service and not Email Communication Service.

Comment: I created an 'email communication service' and there isn't any items listed in 'communication service'. Could you please explain further?

Comment: There must be a resource of type “Communication Service” in the resource group where your “Email Communication Service” is created. Can you please check that?

Comment: unfortunately, there isn't any. Is it supposed to be there because it looks like 'communication service' only manage SMS kind of communications.

Comment: Hmm…that’s weird! Communication Service is an umbrella service and Email/SMS/Phone service are child services under that.

Comment: Oh, Thank you for the clarification. Even though I've created the email communication service, never did a communication service. Now it's working. Thank you for your input and time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Issue after adding Azure Email Communication Service.

My solution:

1. Create an **Azure Communication Service**
2. Go to **Domains** and click on **Connect domain**
3. Select the previously added Email Service
4. Click on **Connect**

[image: Screenshot of Connect domain dialog]